# Garmin BLE heart rate monitor -- cannot get HRM data via Bluetooth, what am I missing?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, garmin

With an unbranded Bluetooth/ANT+ heart rate monitor, I can get the HRM data easily using `gatttool`:

```
<MAC address>> connect
Attempting to connect to <MAC address>
Connection successful
<MAC address>> primary
(...)
<MAC address>> char-desc 0x000c 0x0011
(...)
<MAC address>> char-write-req 0x000f 0100
Characteristic value was written successfully
Notification handle = 0x000e value: 16 34 e4 04 
Notification handle = 0x000e value: 16 34 a5 04 
Notification handle = 0x000e value: 16 33 ea 04 
Notification handle = 0x000e value: 16 33 de 04
```

With this I am sending to handle `0x000f` which is `00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`, which is where I need to send the request ([doc for 0x2902](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Descriptors/org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml)), and I get responses from another handle ([doc for 0x2a37](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml)).

I'm already a bit confused by the `0100` payload that we send. The spec for `0x2902` says that we should send 16 bits, and `0x0100` is `0b100000000`. Does this result in `0b0000000100000000` or in `0b1000000000000000`? Why are we sending `0x0100` and not `0x8000` (i.e. `1` with 15 `0`)?

Anyway, `01`, `010`, `0100`, `01000` will work, but any more digits will fail. Shouldn't it fail with 5 digits already, since 4 hex chars is 16 bits? Anyway, `01` works (Notifications on, Indications off?), `02` will not result in updates (Notifications off, Indications on?), `03` works (Notifications on, Indications on?). Is my understanding sort of correct?

I now take my Garmin heart rate monitor (it's a Garmin HRM Dual). I can connect just fine via Bluetooth to it, I can find the correct handle for HRM interaction (the handle that corresponds to UUID `0x2902`), but when I use `gatttool` to send a `char-write-req` to the handle just like previously, it says the value was written, but nothing ever happens. I've tried a number of values but nothing ever happens.

Am I missing something? Is there any extra step that needs to be taken before calling the HRM handle?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find out what that missing step is?

Answer (score 0):

The 0100 that you are sending is just 0001 in [Little Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Because BlueZ is using Little Endian when writing values, the last byte comes first. For example, if you want to write 01 02 03, you will have to write it as 030201. This is why 01, 010, 0100, and 01000 all work, because in all of these cases you are writing 01. You are also correct about 02 enabling indications, and that 03 would enable both notifications and indications.

As for enabling notifications and reading HRM data, make sure that you are wearing your HRM Dual before you enable notifications. The reason for this is that the HRM Dual will not work unless it detects actual Heart Rate data. You can test this by connecting via the nRF Connect app on your Android/iOS device and trying to read the HRM data.